# Authenticate static pages with passportjs and express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passportjs to authenticate a simple web app. I am able to store the session and check whether the user exists using req.user on pages that are making calls to my node server. However, there I also have static pages that are not making calls -- if someone were to guess the URL of these pages, they'd be able to get into the app without authentication. How can I authenticate these static pages through the server?

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce authentication for static files by adding auth middleware to your route.

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var auth = jwt({secret: 'SECRET', userProperty: 'payload'});

app.use(auth, express.static('public'));
```

If you dont use jwt, a custom function can be passed instead of auth.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.use('/pagecontainer', yourAuthFunction, express.static(__dirname + '/public/pagecontainer'));
```

Define a static route to access the folder where your pages are in, and add the passport authentication (yourAuthFunction) middle-ware function to authenticate requests coming to that folder.